# What explains bond “convenience yields”?

Tags: fixed-income, bond-yields

Bond convenience yield refers to nonpecuniary benefits of holding bonds, that is, some benefit other than direct cash flows. Recently there has been much empirical academic research on such yields.

For example this paper (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3797321) considers yield differences between government bonds issued by different eurozone countries, which simplifies issues as the bonds are dominated in the same currency and share the same policy rate. It adjusts for credit risk using CDS contracts and defines a convenience yield as the resulting difference in same maturity yields. Even controlling for credit risk, it finds that German bonds trade at much lower yields than bonds issued by other countries (the yield differential to southern economies is more than 50 bps).

What explains such convenience yields?

Comment: There might be a few reasons. Some jurisdictions dont have taxes on capital gains and interest income, hence these bonds can have lower yields. Some bonds are more liquid, therefore liquidity premium is lower, some bonds can be pledged as collateral in repo deals or as CSA for derivatives which is particularly useful for liquidity desks at banks. The more useful the bond is, the lower the yield.

Comment: @emot Is this eligibility as collateral related to regulation? Bonds with more credit risk appear to have higher convenience yields. Could it be that banks are not willing to accept riskier bonds as collateral and this decreases the convenience benefit of such bonds?

Comment: The ECB has regulation on the bonds that can are eligible for it's repo facility. I am not sure what the cut-offs are now, but low rated debt was not eligible. Also riskier debt has a higher haircuts when repoing.

Comment: The link to the article in the post isn't working, but if your summary of how they calculate the convenience yield is correct then I think this is not an accurate manner in which to calculate the convenience yield. One should compare forward contracts and spot prices and not use CDSs. The CDS approach only normalises the risk premium for default, but not for downgrades and hence the paper's convenience yield will also include risk premia for non-default events which is not convenience yield related. I think this is also the reason you are seeing the large discrepancies in convenience yield.

Comment: @TrevorHansen Thanks. Could you elaborate why this doesn’t account for downgrade risk? Doesn’t the market value of the CDS go up when there is news about a downgrade?

Comment: @fesman you are right you can replicate bonds with CDSs so this can behave like other derivatives to calculate the convenience yield. I have only worked on convenience yields using forwards, but I suppose this is the same. Apologies and you can ignore my incorrect comment on migration risk.